# cx_oracle unable to find Oracle Client

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I have installd Python 2.7.3 on Linux 64 bit machine. I have Oracle 11g client(64bit) as well installed. And I set ORACLE_HOME, PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and installed cx_oracle 5.1.2 version for Python 2.7 & Oracle 11g. But ldd command on cx_oracle is unable to find libclntsh.so.11.1.

I tried creating symlinks to libclntsh.so.11.1 under /usr/lib64, updated oracle.conf file under /etc/ld.so.conf.d/. Tried all possible solutions that have been discussed on this issue on the forums, but no luck.
Please let me know what am missing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with me was that I installed python, cx_oracle as root but Oracle client installation was done by "oracle" user. I got my own oracle installation and that fixed the issue.

Later I ran into PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeUTF16 issues with Python and for that I had to install python with —enable-unicode=ucs4 option